# Updating data in MySQL in scheduled time

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

I want to UPDATE my data in scheduled time. My problem is that I cant equal the date that I enter in my database in the current real time date. For example, I have 2015/24/9 19:50:00 in my database, now I want to equal it to the current real time date so that I can update a specific row in the database. If I don't do that, the amount field will just multiply 5 in every row. I want to multiply the amount by 5 in a specific row and time

Code:

```
CREATE EVENT myeventsdasa11s
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

DO
  UPDATE messagesd
  SET amount = amount*5
  WHERE DATE = (the the current real time date);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` values are, like floating-point values, difficult to compare for numerical equality.  In other words, if it happens that `NOW() = datetimestamp`, it's a lucky accident.  This is especially true when processing events: the event actually starts to run shortly after the scheduled time.

So, instead of saying something like this

```
 `DATE` = NOW()
```

say something like this

```
 `DATE` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 10 SECOND 
            AND NOW() + INTERVAL 10 SECOND
```

Of course, such a narrow time interval makes you critically dependent on the time accuracy of the event scheduler. You'd be better off adding a `LAST_UPDATED` column of `DATETIME` type to your table, then doing this update.

```
UPDATE messagesd
  SET amount = amount * 5,
      LAST_UPDATED = `DATE`
WHERE `DATE` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE 
  AND (`DATE` > LAST_UPDATED OR LAST_UPDATED IS NULL)
```

That way, every time your event runs you'll update all the rows that are due for update, but haven't yet been updated. This is *not* dependent on the precise time an event runs. The `- INTERVAL 1 MINUTE` allows the event to be up to a minute late running and still function correctly.

If you need to schedule another update for the future for a particular row, change the value of the `DATE` column but don't touch the `LAST_UPDATED` column.

Comment: Is it ok if my DATE column is TIMESTAMP type?

Comment: Yes, you can use `TIMESTAMP` data types. The same sort of problems about equality comparison will come up. Make sure the new `LAST_UPDATED` column datatype matches the `DATE` column datatype.

Comment: Is LAST_UPDATED null?

Comment: I am suggesting that you add the `LAST_UPDATED` column to your table. If you do that, it will have NULL values until you make them non-NULL with your UPDATE query.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for `CURDATE()`?

```
CREATE EVENT myeventsdasa11s
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

DO
  UPDATE messagesd
  SET amount = amount * 5
  WHERE DATE = CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need **the current real date time** use mysql **NOW()**

```
CREATE EVENT myeventsdasa11s
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

DO
  UPDATE messagesd
  SET amount = amount*5
  WHERE DATE = NOW();
```

Comment: Date column should be **DATETIME** type